# Slow Upserts with PyMongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to insert ~800 million records into MongoDB using PyMongo on a macbook air 1.7GHz i7 with no multi-threading, the documents are structured as below:

Records I'm reading are the following tuple:

(user_id,imp_date,imp_creative,imp_pid,geo_id)

I'm creating my own _id field based on the user_id in the file I'm reading from.

```
{_id:user_id,
'imp_date':[array of dates],
'imp_creative':[array of numeric ids],
'imp_pid':[array of numeric ids],
'geo_id':numeric id}
```

I'm using an upsert with $push to append date, creative id, and pid for the corresponding arrays

```
self.collection.update({'_id':uid},
                       {"$push":{'imp_date':<datevalue>,
                                 'imp_creative':<creative_id>,
                                 'imp_pid':<pid>}},safe=True,upsert=True)
```

I'm using an upsert with $set to overwrite the geographic location (only care about most recent.

```
self.collection.update({'_id':uid},
                       {"$set":{'geo_id':<geo id>}},safe=True,upsert=True)
```

I'm only writing about 1,500 records per second (8,000 if I set safe=False). My question is: what can I do to speed this up further (ideally 20k/second or faster)?

Ideas I can't find a definitive recommendation on:
-Using multiple threads to insert data
-Sharding
-Padding arrays (my arrays grow very slowly, each document array will have an average length of ~4 at the end of the file)
-Turning journaling off

Apologies if I've left out any required information, this is my first post.

Comment: Enrique has some good suggestions in his answer.  Have you also tried splitting the batch up and running it on two separate connections/machines?  I just did a basic test and it seemed that the two connections didn't slow each other down.  In other words, threading may make the most significant difference for you.

Answer (score 0):

1- You could add an index to speed it up, and index would help you to find the documents faster although the inserts would be slower (you have to update the index as well). If the improvement in the retrieving phase compensates the extra time to update the index depends on how many records you have in the collections, how many indexes you have and how complicated those indexes are.

However, in your case you are only querying with the _id so there's no much more you can do with indexes.

2- Are you using two consecutive updates? I mean, one for the $set and one for the $push?
If that's true, then you should definetelly use just one:

```
self.collection.update({'_id':uid},
                       {"$push":{'imp_date':<datevalue>,
                                 'imp_creative':<creative_id>,
                                 'imp_pid':<pid>},
                       "$set":{'geo_id':<geo id>}},
                       safe=True,upsert=True)
```

3- The update operation is an atomic operation which might locks other queries. If the document you are about to update is not already in RAM but it is in the disk, mongo will have to first fetch it from the disk and then update it. If you do a find operation first (which doesn't block as it's a read-only operation) the document will be in RAM for sure so the update operation (the locking one) will be faster:

```
self.collection.findOne({'_id':uid})
self.collection.update({'_id':uid},
                       {"$push":{'imp_date':<datevalue>,
                                 'imp_creative':<creative_id>,
                                 'imp_pid':<pid>},
                       "$set":{'geo_id':<geo id>}},
                       safe=True,upsert=True)
```

4-If your documents don't grow too much as you have said, it won't be necessary to bother about padding factor and reallocation issues. Furthermore, in some recent versions (can't remember if it was since 2.2 or 2.4) collections are created with the powerOfTwo option enabled by default.

Comment: Thanks so much. I changed my insert syntax as per recommendation 2 and got performance gains. I tried suggestion 3, but I ran into some concurrency issues when trying multiple threads and ended up with a slower overall performance. For now I think the best thing I can do is use a better machine on AWS and shard (performance seriously degraded as the DB grew on my machine and crawled at around 80M records). Appreciate all the help.